# Exact Layout of the method table in CLR (version 4.0)

Tags: c#, .net, methods, clr, internals

A .NET/CLR-Question: Every object has as its second field a pointer to a method table. How is the exact (exact!) layout of this method table in Version 4.0 of the CLR (x86 Architecture)? It would be nice if You can give me a hint where to find this information (and similar informations concerning the layout of the domain wide interface table).

Comment: Why do you need to know this? And why does it have to be exact?

Comment: I know COM goes to great lengths to describe this type of information but I'm not sure the CLR does.  Could you tell us how you'd like to use this information? May help to point us to a good solution for you.

Comment: Check out this question, the answers to it, and the links they contain. Not necessarily up-to-date for .NET 4.0, but a good start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385653/object-layout-structure-in-net-using-disassembler

Comment: I know this and similar articles. I would like to have it for 4.0. SSCli is great, but not up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The article [“Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx) goes into great detail to describe the method in .Net.

It's from May 2005, so it's not specific to .Net 4, but I doubt anything changed significantly since then.

Comment: There's little reason to assume nothing changed in .NET 4, just the MethodTable class *declaration* is 2599 lines of code in the SSCLI20 version and is heavily interwoven with the rest of the CLR plumbing.  clr/src/vm/methodtable.h source file.  Expecting an exact layout in an answer is off the table.

Comment: I know this and similar articles and I like them. But they are outdated. (The principles may not have changed but the details have.) I would like to trace (with VS2020 and SOS) the implementation of interface method dispatch which I have understood from a C# point of view. Pure curiosity!

Comment: @Cord and have you tried doing that according to the old articles? Maybe those parts that interest you haven't changed. If you encounter problems with that, asking a new specific question might help.

Comment: @svick I have tried! And I will try to formulate a detailed question. But this will take some time. Thank for Your comments!